# Wagtail: Using modeladmin within multilingual websites

Tags: multilingual, wagtail, modeladmin

I have this "PageModel" on my website and want to use modeladmin to add/edit them in a sperate menu.

```
from cities.models import City

class City(Page):
    cityobject = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    streamfield  = StreamField(BasicStreamBlock, null=True, blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('cityobject', classname="full"),
        StreamFieldPanel('streamfield'),
    ]
```

I also use this approach for a multilingual website:
http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/advanced_topics/i18n/duplicate_tree.html

What I want is within wagtail admin to have a button "Cities" beside the explorer to add cities. But before I add them, I would like to select for which website. For example:

Cities -> EN -> London

Cities -> DE -> Berlin

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you register a ModelAdmin class for a page type that can exist in more than one part of the tree, when you use the 'Add' button at the top of the listing to add a new page, you should be prompted automatically to choose a parent for it (before being presented with the page editor interface).

The behaviour actually changes depending on the logged-in user's permissions. For example, if the user can add pages to any part of the tree, then they would be prompted to choose what the parent page should be. But, for a user with limited permissions, who might only be able to add pages to one of the possible parents - the one possible option would be identified automatically, and the user wouldn't be prompted.

EDIT:

If you want to add additional menu items to the menu in the Wagtail admin area, you might want to consider using a `ModelAdminGroup` class for your app instead, and overriding the [get_submenu_items](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/options.py#L546) method to append custom [`MenuItem`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/admin/menu.py#L11) instances to the list before returning. If you can copy the URL pattern used on the 'Add' button at the top of the listing, you should get the same conditional 'Choose a parent' functionality as described above.

If you haven't used the `ModelAdminGroup` class before, an example of use can be found in the docs: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/modeladmin/#a-more-complicated-example